# Is "will have had been" a valid verb tense?

Tags: tenses

As in: "By the time you arrive, I will have had been walking for 2 hours".  Meaning that you had been walking for 2 hours but stopped.

Comment: It looks valid to me, but I believe that the phrase can be shortened to "I will have been walking...". The 'had' can be dropped.

Comment: No, that particular phrase never appears in English. In the sentence you cite, the verb phrase should be _will have been walking for 2 hours_. No _had_ after _have_.

Comment: *I will have had* needs to be followed by a ***noun***, not more ***verbs***. For example, *By the time you arrive, I will have had **2 hours of walking***.